# R DT filter disabled and greyed

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In R Shiny applications, at what situations will the filter boxes get greyed.

Like, is there a limit on the number of filters can be applied to a datatable?

I searched https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ but didn't find anything relevant.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The greyed out space means that You have only one unique value in the column (not more then one option in the column to filter)